Least squares using scalaPACK
I'm learning to use scalaPACK least squares pdgels routine but cannot get it to work.
I would appreciate your insight on this matter.
The code below suppose to distribute 8x8 matrix A to 4 local 4x4 matrices A_loc and similarly for vector B. The blacs grid is 2x2. The code is intended to be run with 4 MPI tasks.
The code compiles and runs with the following output with one MPI task:
BEFORE: Local B size 8 on rank: 0 values: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
AFTER: Local B size 8 on rank: 0 values: 0.960918 0.0252256 0.0222086 0.0319953 -0.0471391 0.0205009 -0.0163878 0.00267855 

This looks about right, the B_loc has been updated with solution from least squares.
However when four MPI tasks are used I'm getting the following result:
BEFORE: Local B size 4 on rank: 0 values: 1 2 3 4 
BEFORE: Local B size 4 on rank: 1 values: 4.68603e-310 0 2.122e-314 2.122e-314 
BEFORE: Local B size 4 on rank: 2 values: 5 6 7 8 
BEFORE: Local B size 4 on rank: 3 values: 4.67566e-310 0 2.122e-314 2.122e-314 
AFTER: Local B size 4 on rank: 1 values: 4.68603e-310 0 2.122e-314 2.122e-314 
AFTER: Local B size 4 on rank: 2 values: 5 6 7 8 
AFTER: Local B size 4 on rank: 3 values: 4.67566e-310 0 2.122e-314 2.122e-314 
AFTER: Local B size 4 on rank: 0 values: 0.321957 1.12458 -0.21503 -0.231507 

What surprises me is that only the values of the B_loc on rank 0 have been updated with presumably part of the least squares solution. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>

extern "C" void blacs_get_(int*, int*, int*);
extern "C" void blacs_pinfo_(int*, int*);
extern "C" void blacs_gridinit_(int*, char*, int*, int*);
extern "C" void blacs_gridinfo_(int*, int*, int*, int*, int*);
extern "C" void descinit_(int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*);
extern "C" void blacs_gridexit_(int*);
extern "C" int numroc_(int*, int*, int*, int*, int*);
extern "C" void pdgels_(char* trans, int* m, int* n, int* nrhs, double* a, int* ia, int* ja, int* desca, double* b, int* ib, int* jb, int* descb, double* work, int* lwork, int* info);
extern "C" void pdgemr2d_(int *m, int *n, double *a, int *ia, int *ja, int *desca,
    double *b, int *ib, int *jb, int *descb, int *context);

int main() {

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int rank, size;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  int b_nrows, b_ncols, b_row, b_col, myid;
  blacs_pinfo_( &myid, &size );
  char layout = 'R';

  b_nrows = sqrt(size);
  b_ncols = sqrt(size);

  int context;
  int izero=0;
  int ione=1;
  blacs_get_( &izero, &izero, &context );
  blacs_gridinit_( &context, &layout, &b_nrows, &b_ncols );
  blacs_gridinfo_( &context, &b_nrows, &b_ncols, &b_row, &b_col );

  int m=8;  // rows of the global array
  int n=8;  // cols
  int mb=m;
  int nb=n;
  int mb_loc=m/b_nrows;
  int nb_loc=n/b_ncols;

  // size of local arrays
  int m_loc = numroc_( &m, &mb_loc, &b_row, &izero, &b_nrows );
  int n_loc = numroc_( &n, &nb_loc, &b_col, &izero, &b_ncols );

  // global
  double *A = new double[m*n] ;
  double *B = new double[m] ;
  // local
  double *A_loc = new double[m_loc*n_loc] ;
  double *B_loc = new double[m_loc] ;

  int descA[9], descB[9], descA_loc[9], descB_loc[9];
  int info;
  descinit_( descA,  &m, &n, &mb, &nb, &izero, &izero, &context, &m, &info);
  descinit_( descB,  &m, &ione, &mb, &ione, &izero, &izero, &context, &m, &info);

  descinit_( descA_loc,  &m, &n, &mb_loc, &nb_loc, &izero, &izero, &context, &m_loc, &info);
  descinit_( descB_loc,  &m, &ione, &mb_loc, &ione, &izero, &izero, &context, &m_loc, &info);

  // generate column major order matrix
  for (int i = 0; i < m*n; i++) {
    A[i] = i+1;
  }
  // and vector of tagets
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    B[i] = (i+1);
  }

  // distribute matrices
  pdgemr2d_(&m, &n, A, &ione, &ione, descA,
      A_loc, &ione, &ione, descA_loc, &context);

  pdgemr2d_(&m, &ione, B, &ione, &ione, descB,
      B_loc, &ione, &ione, descB_loc, &context);

  std::cout  << "BEFORE: Local B size " << m_loc << " on rank: " << rank << " values: ";
  for (int r = 0; r < m_loc; r++) {
      std::cout << B_loc[r] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  char trans='N';
  int nrhs = 1;
  int ia=1;
  int ja=1;
  int ib=1;
  int jb=1;

  int lwork=-1;
  double wkopt;

  pdgels_(&trans, &m_loc, &n_loc, &nrhs, A_loc, &ia, &ja, descA_loc,
      B_loc, &ib, &jb, descB_loc, &wkopt, &lwork, &info);

  lwork = (int)wkopt;
  double *work= new double[lwork];


  pdgels_(&trans, &m_loc, &n_loc, &nrhs, A_loc, &ia, &ja, descA_loc,
      B_loc, &ib, &jb, descB_loc, work, &lwork, &info);

  std::cout  << "AFTER: Local B size " << m_loc << " on rank: " << rank << " values: ";
  for (int r = 0; r < m_loc; r++) {
      std::cout << B_loc[r] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  delete [] work, A , B, A_loc, B_loc;
  blacs_gridexit_(&context);
  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}



After a little bit of digging (in fact a lot) I manged to identify the issue.
The documentation for pdgels mention that 2nd and 3rd argument are dimensions of a GLOBAL matrix A.
https://netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/dc/d96/pdgels_8f_source.html
However, I've been using IBM documentation with the assumption that it is pretty much the same. It is not. IBM uses dimensions of the local matrix (not global).
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/pessl/5.5?topic=subroutines-pdgels-pzgels-general-matrix-least-squares-solution
Therefore the simple solution is to change the following code
  pdgels_(&trans, &m_loc, &n_loc, &nrhs, A_loc, &ia, &ja, descA_loc,
      B_loc, &ib, &jb, descB_loc, &wkopt, &lwork, &info);

to
  pdgels_(&trans, &m, &n, &nrhs, A_loc, &ia, &ja, descA_loc,
      B_loc, &ib, &jb, descB_loc, &wkopt, &lwork, &info);

Anyway, I hope someone will find it useful.
